# How to revert Perforce to previous stable state?

Tags: perforce

I have a project using Perforce. The scenario I am looking at is like below :

Multiple users submit their changes to Perforce repository and I would like to take a snapshot before syncing. I want to be able to revert if new release has some problems.

Basically I want to create a snapshot of current file which I can view with 'p4 have' and then revert to 'p4 have' files after syncing to head revision! How can I do that !

I tried to use 'p4 tag -l rel1 //depot/', but this command creates a label for head revision. I am looking for a way to do some command like this 'p4 label have' ! Is it possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify that you want the label to include just the files currently in your workspace:

`p4 tag -l rel1 //depot/...#have`

Or better yet use this shortcut:

`p4 label myws` (define the label)
`p4 labelsync` (labels what you currently have in your workspace)

Then you can restore with:

`p4 sync @myws`

Comment: Do you know what is the difference between `p4 tag -l rel1 //depot/...#have` and `p4 tag -l rel1 //depot/...#have,#have` ?